# django - how to redirect page after save modelform

Tags: python, django, redirect

I want to redirtect page, after saving modelform. when i pushed save button, page redirecte, but no any things saved.

```
def channelAdd(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChannelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            channelid = form.cleaned_data['channelid']
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('updateChannelInfo', args=[channelid]))

    else:
        form = ChannelForm()

    return render(request, 'web/channelAdd.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Could you post your models

Comment: your code look good to me..
it is not redirect due to `form` may not `valid`.

Comment: I agree with @vinaykumar: you code looks valid. Probably the form is not saved due to being invalid. Also, it's better to use class based view `UpdateView` that handles all the details like saving and redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you closer to the solution. I'm not positive if you have 'updateChannelInfo' as the name in urls.py (so please double-check that). I think the complexity here is getting the correct channelId to be sent

```
def channelAdd(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChannelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            channelid = form.cleaned_data['channelid']
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('updateChannelInfo', args = [self.object.id])))
    else:
        form = ChannelForm()
    return render(request, 'web/channelAdd.html', {'form':form})
```

If you are willing to share your urls.py and forms.py files, this would help with getting the correct names into arguments

Another way I have had success with the dynamic direct after form submission is to use

```
def add_channel (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChannelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            channel.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('channel_detail', args=[channel.id]))
    else:
        form = ChannelForm()
        return render(request, 'channel_example.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit your view like this,

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('updateChannelInfo', channelId=self.object.id)
```

Comment: please feel free to add a comment after downvoting, it may help to make better answer next time..

Comment: Fazil, you code has an incorrect `HttpResponseRedirect` constructor invocation (I guess you meant `django.shortcuts.redirect` because `HttpResponseRedirect` accepts different arguments). Also, it doesn't answer the question at all.